# How do I enable PHP functions from CLI?

Tags: php, amazon-ec2

I need to check and enable certain php functions in an AWS EC2 instance. (Listed them below). I've gone through the php.ini file but I can't find any reference to any of these. I also don't see them when I run `php -i`. Do I need to install them one by one? If so, do how do I do this on the unix command line?

These are the functions

> mbstring modules, zip and enabled gd2. 
>   PHP functions enabled: 
>   - dir 
>   - readdir 
>   - opendir 
>   - eval 
>   - exec 
>   - set_time_limit 
>   - ini_alter 
>   - ini_set 
>   - ini_restore 
>   - php_uname 
>   - popen 
>   - proc_close 
>   - proc_get_status 
>   - proc_open 
>   - shell_exec 
>   - system

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Have you installed PHP-CLI?

Answer (score 1):

you are a dealing with php extensions/modules, you could reconfigure your php installation and [rebuild](http://php.net/manual/en/mbstring.installation.php) it

or you could add it as an library. they are located in `{your php installation dir}/extensions/`

also see http://php.net/manual/en/function.dl.php

Personally, I would build php from scratch with only the extension you need.